# Is it possible to customize Buefy using CDN?

Tags: cdn, buefy

I am using CDN Buefy and I want to change some colors, is there a way to do that without needing to install Buefy through npm?

Comment: Yes, you can do it using custom css. Simple create another style.css file after Buefy CDN. then, select the classes you want to change the color. It will override the Buefy styles.

Comment: I mean, I want to change Buefy defaults like the `is_primary` in `<b-button type="is-primary">push</b-button>`

Comment: No, you can't do that